# Display pictures with text after async activity

Tags: android, image, text, android-asynctask

I am new in android development and I am trying to display some small images (small country flags) with some description text next to each of them.
What I am doing is to create an async job which connects to internet retrieves the information that I need and fills some variables in a class and at the end it returns an object of this class.
The function onPostExecute

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        System.out.println(xmlData.getCurrency("USD"));
        try {
            activReg.getResult(xmlData);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("MESSAGE GET RESULT"+e.getMessage());
        }
   }
```

Function getResult in the MainActivity looks like

```
public void getResult(Currency xmlObj){
   LinearLayout right = new LinearLayout(this);
   Resources resource = getResources();
   ImageView imgUsd = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.usd);
   final Drawable drawable = imgUsd.getDrawable();
   TextView res = new TextView(this);
   imgUsd.setImageDrawable(drawable);
   res.setText("EUR=>USD: "+Double.toString(xmlObj.getCurrency("USD")));
   //res.setText("EUR=>GBP: "+Double.toString(xmlObj.getCurrency("GBP")));
   setContentView(res);
```

}

Now as you can see I messed up a little bit everything and tried so many things which didn't work anyway. So what I am trying to achieve is to have a list of `xmlObj.getCurrency("USD")`, `xmlObj.getCurrency("GBP")` etc with a small flag image next to them. Of course if I use setText more than one, the last one overwrites the previous one and this brings me to my two questions:

1. How can I add more text in a layout?
2. How can I add images which are defined(or not) in the main xml layout?

For your information the layout is `LinearLayout` and I also tried to include the image in this way:

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/usd"
    android:layout_width="59dp" 
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/usd" />
```

in the xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is this:-

```
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        System.out.println(xmlData.getCurrency("USD"));
        try {
            activReg.getResult(xmlData);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("MESSAGE GET RESULT"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**Are you loading xmlObj one by one or all xmlObj together??**

You can create a xml with listview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Later in your getResult method write up

```
  View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false);
    setContentView(view);
    ArrayList<YourModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<YourModel>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < xmlObj[].length; i++){
      YourModel model = new YourModel;
      model.setUsd(Double.toString(xmlObj.getCurrency("USD"));
      model.setImageUrl(xmlObj.getString("Url"));
      arrayList.add(model);
    }
    CustomArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(context,R.id.list_item,arrayList);
    ListView view = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    view.setadapter(arrayAdapter);
```

The YourModel will be a separate java class which will have image url and text description
which will have getters and setters.

**R.id.list_item** :-you will need to create another xml for creating list row which will have imageView and textview aligned horizontally.

The customArrayAdapter will be custom adapter for which you can find tutorials.

If still doubt you can always ask..    :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use list view if you have multiple images with description.
You can follow [ListView tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#androidlists_overview)

Comment: I am following the tutorial that you posted. I'll see what I can get out of it.

Comment: I am sure I'm missing something, but the problem is to create this list in getResult() after being called from the async job onPostExecute(). The tutorial only shows how to do that in the main activity. How can I create this listview with text and icons?

Comment: You can call your method getResult() in onPostExecute()
U can inflate xml in your method

Comment: It might be easy for you, but it's not for me. Can you please be more detailed about this? Probably I am doing something rather complicate to achieve something which can easily be done: start the application, an async job reads and parse an xml and when it's done sends the object to the main activity which is supposed to show these data with some pictures in the main layout.